# If I only want to download and test a file locally using TFS 2013 how do I do this?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I just started at a company that uses Team Foundation Server to house all the programming code.  Say, I want to use my Visual Studio 2013 to download some files from TFS, maybe edit them, and try them out on my local machine, how do I do this?  I think I just have to select "Get Latest Version" from the TFS menu.  Can anyone confirm?

Note, if I make edits to these files, I don't want to load them back to TFS at this point.  I just want to be able to download some files from TFS and play with them on my local machine to get a feel for things (but want to make sure I don't disturb/change any of the files that are on TFS).  If that is the case, is "Get Latest Version" what I need to click?

Also, for future reference, later, when I actually do want to make "real" edits to these files and upload them back to TFS, then what I need to do is:  Get Latest Version --> Check Out for Edit --> (make my edits and save) --> Check In

Is that correct?

Also, why don't they write an easy book on how to use TFS for the regular programmer?  All the books on Amazon are about setting up TFS and administering it - but there is no short easy book that teaches a programmer at a new job how to use TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can go ahead and `Get Latest Version` though you will likely have to set up a local workspace (which as a beginner you can just think of as a folder) and map your application to that.

The easiest way is to just `File > Open Solution From Source Control` and it will prompt you as necessary. After that you can just open the solution from Visual Studio start page.

You don't have to worry about overwriting anything until you check it back in via the `Check In` command which is an explicit command.

Even if you absolutely screw everything up it's not too big of a deal because all your changes are collected into a change set that can be rolled back. You won't want to screw it up for professional reasons but if you do it's not the end of the world.

Regarding "real edits", you can just `Check-In`. Depending on how your team is structured you may not have to check-out which locks the file. A good habit is too always to do a `Compare` before you commit any pending changes and to commit frequently (hours, not days) so things don't move too far under you.

TFS can seem a little daunting at first but it's actually pretty straight forward. Don't worry about feeling like a idiot for a week or two. I think most people do.

Comment: rism:  Wow, thanks a lot for your help.  It does help a lot.  I actually had a small incident where I did edit and save a small change on a test file and I did some other things (I forgot exactly what I did yesterday), but I after I did it, I realized I shouldn't have done that, freaked out.  Luckily, I clicked the Rollback or Undo Pending Changes and it undid everything I did.

You are right that TFS can seem daunting at first.  But, I think it will start to make more sense soon.  Thanks again.